# Non-negative integers

Tags: haskell, types

Say i have a function prototype as follows:

```
func :: [Int] -> [Int]
```

How is it possible to enforce only a non-negative list of integers as input arguments? I would have to change the param type from [Int] to what.. ? At this fair moment it works with func [-1,-2], i only want it to work with [1,2] i.e. with the interpreter spewing the error message.

Comment: It may look a bit odd to mark a question as a duplicate of a *newer* question. But I think here it makes sense, because the answers at the marked duplicate cover a wider range of options and are more carefully explained.

Answer (score 8):

```
newtype NonNegative a = NonNegative a

toNonNegative :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> NonNegative a
toNonNegative x
  | x < 0 = error "Only non-negative values are allowed."
  | otherwise = NonNegative x

fromNonNegative :: NonNegative a -> a
fromNonNegative (NonNegative x) = x
```

Just be careful to never use the NonNegative constructor directly.  This will be easier if you put this in a separate module and don't export it.

Also, now you can use (map toNonNegative) to lazily transform a list of numbers.

This will still require a runtime check wherever you inject raw numbers.

Alternatively, you can use Data.Word.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried http://hackage.haskell.org/package/non-negative ?

Comment: I hoping that someone would show how to do this with types, but now I can see that this is impossible - from the comment for the NonNegative.C type class in non-negative: "Instances of this class must ensure non-negative values. We cannot enforce this by types, but the type class constraint NonNegative.C avoids accidental usage of types which allow for negative numbers." How disappointing :-)

Answer (score 2):

In the base package with version >= 4.8.0.0, which is included in GHC 7.10.1 and above, there is now a type [Natural](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Numeric-Natural.html) which does what you want - you can just change your code to:

```
import Numeric.Natural (Natural)

func :: [Natural] -> [Int]
```

It is, however, closer to `Integer` than to `Int`, because like `Integer` and unlike `Int`, it has no maximum value.

Because `Natural`, like `Integer`, is an instance of `Num` and `Integral`, all the same arithmetic operations and conversion functions are available as you get with `Integer`. Attempts to calculate a negative `Natural` will throw an `Underflow` at runtime, which is an `ArithException`. Also, conveniently, you can create a `Natural` using just an integer literal, without a conversion:

```
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :m +Numeric.Natural 
Prelude Numeric.Natural> 2 :: Natural
2
```

However, if you would prefer to stay in the domain of fixed-size integers, there is a solution for that, too - and it has been around for far longer - `Word` from [the module Data.Word](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Word.html) (which also contains e.g. `Word8` for 8-bit non-negative integers). You would use `Word` in the same way as `Natural`. However, be warned - the `Word` types will silently underflow, without throwing an exception:

```
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :m +Data.Word
Prelude Data.Word> 2 :: Word
2
Prelude Data.Word> it - 4
18446744073709551614
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Peano numbers](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/peano-inf), changing your function's type to `[Peano] -> ...`. But then you will have to add conversion functions from integers to peano numbers and back whenever you call your function.

Or you could add a runtime check:

```
func xs
  | any (< 0) xs  = error "only non-negative integers allowed as input"
  | otherwise     = ...
```

Note that the latter solution makes your function [strict](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_function).

Answer (score 1):

The wiki page on [smart constructors](http://haskell.org/haskellwiki/Smart_constructors) may give you some idea.