# Haskell allow only positive input

Tags: haskell

I need to define a haskell function:

```
func :: Int -> Int
func 1 = 1
func 2 = 2
func x = x+1
```

So that it allows only positive numbers. I've already had a look at a similar question: [Non-negative integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070989/non-negative-integers)

And wrote this:

```
newtype Positive a = Positive a

toPositive :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> Positive a
toPositive x
    | x < 0 = error "number cannot be negative"
    | otherwise = Positive x

func :: Positive a -> a
func (Positive n) = n
```

Which is however already throwing errors. Thoughts?

Update:

Sample error:

```
*Main> func 1

<interactive>:32:6:
    No instance for (Num (Positive a0)) arising from the literal `1'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num (Positive a0))
    In the first argument of `func', namely `1'
    In the expression: func 1
    In an equation for `it': it = func 1
*Main>
```

Comment: It works perfectly for me. What errors are you getting?

Comment: Updated above with sample error

Comment: Try calling `func $ toPositive 1`

Comment: It works with positive values, but I get the following for negative:
*Main> func $ toPositive -1

<interactive>:34:8:
    Couldn't match expected type `Positive a0'
                with actual type `a1 -> Positive a1'
    In the first argument of `(-)', namely `toPositive'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `toPositive - 1'
    In the expression: func $ toPositive - 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to call `toPositive` to convert an `Int` to a `Positive`. Call it this way:

```
func $ toPositive 1
```

Also, a quirk of Haskell is its handling of negative number literals. To avoid confusion with the subtraction operator, you must wrap them in parentheses:

```
func $ toPositive (-1)
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah, this works :) Is there any way that I can avoid calling "$  toPositive" and just use "func (-1)"?

Comment: Also, when I try adding "func 0 = 0" or "func (Positive 0) = 0" I get... dynprog.hs:9:16:
    No instance for (Num a) arising from the literal `0'
    Possible fix:
      add (Num a) to the context of
        the type signature for func :: Positive a -> a
    In the pattern: 0
    In the pattern: Positive 0
    In an equation for `func': func (Positive 0) = 2
Failed, modules loaded: none.

Comment: You could write a new `func` that takes an `Int` as an argument, and calls toPositive internally. However that starts to defeat the purpose of what you're doing. If you make a new type, you have to convert to and from that type. You could also scrap the `Positive` type entirely, and just explicitly check for negative input in `func`.

Comment: I've tried doing that, but then when I try returning an error I get an error saying an "Int" was expected as a return type?

Comment: If your question has gotten larger, consider making another edit to your question, posting more code and a fuller explanation of what you're trying to do, and what errors you're getting. Comments are an inefficient way to have this conversation.